# UI Thread gets stuck even though I'm working on another

Tags: java, android, multithreading, ui-thread, countdownlatch

I have this code that on a click of a button a service will be started from a new thread and the service will start my TCP Client.

The TCP client, once connected will send a count down event to inform the fragment to continue working.

the code looks like this

```
   connectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.connectBT);
        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {

                            // ***** IntentService Way ****** //
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NetworkService.class);
                            getActivity().startService(intent);

                            // Once client is connected, give the server some info about client
                            mCountDown.await(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                            String json = jsonMaker.toJson(new DeviceInfo());
                            DispatchToServer(json);
                        } catch (Exception ie) {
                            ie.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }).run();
```

but when I click connect, my UI still freezes for some reason, even though I'm waiting on a different thread then the UI thread. Same code worked fine when I used an AsyncTask instead of the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have written

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {...}).run();
```

`Thread#run` is just the `Thread` class's implementation of the `Runnable` interface. All it does is delegate to the `run` method of the `Runnable` you have passed to the constructor.

Java threads are started with the `start` method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {...}).start();
```

Comment: Thank you, I do know this but for some reason I got a black out on this very important detail. Feel like a dumbass

Comment: It's a very common pitfall. A good way to avoid it is to simply *not* use raw Threads; instead prefer an Executor Service.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call thread.start() instead of thread.run()

Answer (score 3):

Use Thread.start() instead of Thread.run()

Comment: I'm such a moron! Thats what happens when you work on code when you'r tired. thanks!